# Find a unicode character in string with Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I'm new to python and maybe this question is not so smart, but anyway I cannot solve this small issue.
As usual, for instance in a conditional statement, to find some a character or a substring in a string I'm used to write the following code:

```
if 'a' in myvariable:
    <do something>
```

However, if the character or substring are unicode characters with an high code-point, for instance a ⸣ (half square-bracket), I get the following error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

I understand the problem, but I cannot figure it out how to solve it.

Of course I'm working with python 2.7

**EDIT**

This is my true iteration and some clarifications follow:

```
if '⸣' not in myvariable:
    newvariable = 100.0
```

I have to test if '⸣' is not in myvariable: myvariable type is already `<type 'unicode'>`, whereas the unicode character '⸣' (Unicode Code Point U+2E23) is out of the range of ASCII characters.
Moreover the scripts already make use of the pragma `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

Many thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why implicit conversion of byte strings to Unicode strings was removed in Python 3.

You're almost there, with the `#coding` line at the start of your file. Just one tiny change to turn your test character into a Unicode string:

```
if u'⸣' not in myvariable:
    newvariable = 100.0
```

You might have trouble with that particular character as I did on my system, so you can use the equivalent escape sequence instead:

```
if u'\u2e23' not in myvariable:
    newvariable = 100.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, if I well understand, anytime I must compare a test character against a unicode string, the test character must be _unicode-ed_. Sorry for this answer... but, when the test character is in the range of ASCII characters, does python convert it in unicode implicitly?

Comment: @Pankus yes, Python 2.7 will convert an ASCII string to Unicode implicitly when you try to use it in an operation with a Unicode string. It's convenient when it works, frustrating when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the unicode as eg: `var = u'e`' and do the following operation `var.find('a')` to find the character in the unicode variable.

Hope this works !!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try changing the file encoding type to make it work.
Refer this doc:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

You can change the file's encoding type to UTF-8 by adding this to your source file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Example

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
b = '⸣fdsf'
if 'd' in b:
    print 'd'
```

Answer (score -1):

Work with python 3? 
I think you can import a module for text no?

Comment: how can I do that? Sorry, I'm really a newby